# How is WordPress redirecting/rewriting my URL?

Tags: wordpress

i'm running a wordpress free classified website and the address is http://www.gosell.co.uk what i need is if a user from london open this url then it should be concatenated with http://www.gosell.co.uk/longon how is that possible? shall i make a new function or wat? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? What do you want to happen if a user visits the `/london` URL?

Comment: The thing is my site is running in uk and i want to make it local classified u know i mean? if some open a site in manchester the my site should show him manchester local ad and my site url should be http://www.gosell.co.uk/manchester or manchester.gosell.co.uk i want a ciry redirect thats wat i want. and i ll detect user by their ip addresses.
i hope explained it clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook into `init` action (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action), detect where is your visitor from using some of available geoip solutions, and then use `wp_redirect` to redirect to the right url...